# OperationalError: FATAL: role "...." does not exist

Tags: postgresql, openerp-7

I have a server (Ubuntu 12.4) with Openerp 7 and postgresql.
When I run openerp with this command :

```
    sudo service openerp start
```

it works (I think it's called the daemon).

So i tried to execute it "directly" with the executable file:

```
    sudo service openerp stop
    /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/openerp -c /etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf
```

At the begginning there was the error as follows "OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied**" so I edited the pg_hba.conf like I saw in this website
http://ujwalafossist.blogspot.com/2015/01/operationalerror-fesendauth-no-password.html

I tried many things and now my pg_hba.conf file is like this :
[image]

So now when I run

```
     /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/openerp -c /etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf
```

and refresh openerp in my navigator I have got errors
[image]
[image]
Maybe it's a tip, but when I execute the command, before refreshing I see in the terminal
[image]
But i don't want to use eggs i want to use eggspg

---

EDIT : when I run 'sudo su postgres', I enter in my database and enter \du : I have 3 roles : eggspg, openerp and postgres (but no eggs). 
[image]

Therefore when I run the daemon it works; and when I run the command directly, the configuration file has db_user = eggspg
[image]

Comment: On a Odoo v10 I succeed, I edited the pg_hba file (`sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf`) but beside # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only, not beside #Database administrative login by inux domain socket
and giving access right to a directory `sudo chown -R adquat .local/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : its mandatory to change the pg_hba file

> ' # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only '
>
> ' local  all all trust '

and to use the db user and the db password :

`python /usr/bin/openerp -c /etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf -r openerp -w mypassword`
or

`python /usr/bin/openerp -c /etc/openerp/openerp-server.conf --db_user=openerp --db_password=mypassword`